# Fancybox just loading small white square

Tags: images, jquery

I've tried what I could, but cannot get my image to load with the fancybox plugin. The plugin is there, and seems to load, but without the image. Instead I get a small white square on the top left of my screen.

I read I may have to put this in my footer.php file, which upon checking seems to be there:

`<?php wp_footer(); ?>`

So, otherwise I don't know where else to check. Here is the page / file in question:
http://testsite.mattlorenzi.ca/corel-draw-logo-instructions/

Comment: The error says: _Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'v.easing[this.easing]' is not a function_ – did you load all necessary JavaScript files?

Comment: @toscho
Not sure, just installed the Easy FancyBox plugin in Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site; there's  404 for a JS file called main.js, probably from Fancybox. Your main jQuery libraries are loading OK.

Comment: I change the transition setting from "elastic" to "fade", and it worked.